# What should we do with [grammar] questions?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

In a previous question and answer, a consensus developed that [grammar](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grammar) is not something we want to keep around: [Do we want the [grammar] tag?](https://latin.meta.stackexchange.com/q/56/12)

But the tag was never blacklisted, and we're now up to 23 questions with the tag.  Before it gets any bigger, it seems appropriate to attempt to work out how we categorize the various types of questions that the tag is receiving.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd suggest that there are three categories of questions in this tag, two of which would use new tags:

1. Questions asking what a particular word's grammatical function is ("Grammar Identification" – [grammar-identification](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grammar-identification))
2. Questions asking which grammatical form to use in a particular situation ("Grammar Choice" – [grammar-choice](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grammar-choice))

   - This is different from [translation](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/translation), which includes questions asking about both vocabulary and grammar
3. Questions where [grammar](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grammar) isn't needed, because other tags already capture the content of the question ("Remove Grammar Tag")

Applying these categories to the 23 [grammar](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grammar) questions, I would break them down as follows:

- Grammar Identification

  - ["Ignis solis propinqui"](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/95)
  - [“Dies unus”—non primus?](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/98)
  - [Nonne "a fortiori, a priori, a posteriori" solecismi sunt?](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/133)
  - [How do I understand “victís” and “imperitátum” in this sentence from Livy XXI?](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/249)
  - [Why “impressa” in Æneid IV.659-60?](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/250)
  - [How is "quod" operating in this sentence of Hyginus?](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/268)
  - ["omniaque perpeti ipsa" in De Finibus](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/919)
  - [In the title "Ars Goetia," is "Goetia" an appositive noun?](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/944)
- Grammar Choice

  - [Are there examples of passive imperative forms of non-deponent verbs in ancient literature?](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/62)
  - [Is the Phrase "Sola Dea Fatum Novit" Proper Latin?](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/203)
  - [Is "esse est percipi" grammatical, even with infinitives?](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/525)
  - [Is `duco sanitas` a grammatically correct way of saying `I lead health`?](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/585)
  - [Perfect passive forms like "amatus fuit"](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/621)
  - [Can Latin "inde" introduce a temporal clause?](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/924)
  - [Difference between Vocative and Accusative usage](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/1016)
- Remove Grammar Tag

  - [When can I perform an elision?](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/51) (poetry)
  - [Technique to find first principal parts when later parts change spelling? e.g. find 'nanciscor' from 'nactus'](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/132) (orthography)
  - [When did Latin lose the locative?](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/311) (locative)
  - [Were there grammatical disagreements in Latin?](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/885) (grammarians; *maybe* grammar-choice)
  - [How many distinct forms does a typical Latin verb have?](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/921) (verbs)
  - [Is "Homo sum, Deus ero" a correct way to say this?](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/932) (translation)
  - [What is a "second-person singular future active indicative" verb?](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/1042) (verbs)
  - [Is "scholaris opus, scholaris vox" a correct translation of "student work, student voice"?](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/947) (translation)

Of course, you might disagree with my specific applications of these three categories.  I include this detail only to show how I'm envisioning the two new tags would be used.  If you see a better way to categorize these questions, or better tag names, offer another answer!

Comment: I mostly agree with your list, but a couple of questions seem to fall between the categories. Would it make sense to add a tag "proofreading" for questions like "is this grammatical" (some of them do not involve making a choice)? We can make "proofreading" and "grammar-choice" synonyms, but having both of them might make the tags easier to find.

Comment: Suggested changes: (1) Remove grammar tag from "When can I perform an elision?" (2) Use "proofreading" or "grammar-confirmation" or something in that direction for the appropriate questions now under Grammar Choice.

Comment: Good point on the elision question; edited.  I'm open to a grammar-confirmation tag as well, though it may be difficult to separate such questions from "grammar-choice" on one side and "translation" on the other.  Maybe it's okay if questions have grammar-confirmation as well as one of these two.

Comment: Having "grammar-confirmation", to be mainly used with "grammar-choice" or "translation" sounds good to me. The tags need not be exclusive.

Comment: I think we can make the clearest tag edits already. (I already did some, but not many, to avoid flooding the front page.) I would let the trickier ones keep their tags until more people weigh in with their opinions here.

Comment: Excellent answer! A choice can be implicit: whenever you're in doubt whether x is correct, you will probably think there are other possibilities (for it must be possible to say whatever you want to say in *some* way). So I would be fine with *grammar choice* for proofreading/confirmation questions about grammar. Although of course proofreading and confirmation are also possible.

Comment: I made some edits today, mostly removing grammar tags. I wonder if there are suitable tags for ["Were there grammatical disagreements in Latin?"](http://latin.stackexchange.com/q/885/79) besides `grammarians`. A `sociology` tag might fit, but I'm not sure.

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta Perhaps `language-evolution` is close enough?

Comment: I guess that is the closest hit among current tags.